# Grails Unit Testing with Composite Keys

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-orm, composite-key

I'm trying to unit test a method where an object with a composite key is being inserted into the database.  Whenever I run my unit test for this, I get the following.

```
Failure:  |
testTransaction(com.myapp.foo.TestServiceSpec)
 |
Condition not satisfied:

Transaction.count() == 1
            |       |
            0       false

    at com.myapp.foo.TestServiceSpec.testTransaction(TestServiceSpec.groovy:166)
```

If I remove the composite key code and nothing else from my domain class, the test passes.

This is my Domain Class, Transaction.groovy:

```
class Transaction implements Serializable {
    String timestamp
    String source
    String tableName
    String fieldName
    Integer changeNumber
    String fieldValue
    String objectId

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ["timestamp", "source", "tableName", "fieldName", "changeNumber"], generator: 'assigned'
    }

    boolean equals(other) {
        if (!(other instanceof Transaction)) {
            return false
        }

        other.timestamp == timestamp && other.source == source && other.id == id && other.tableName == tableName && other.fieldName == fieldName && other.changeNumber == changeNumber
    }

    int hashCode() {
        def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
        builder.append timestamp
        builder.append source
        builder.append tableName
        builder.append fieldName
        builder.append changeNumber
        builder.toHashCode()
    }
}
```

This is the code that's being tested:

```
def response = [code: 'OK']
def transaction = new Transaction()

transaction.timestamp  = (new Date()).format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
transaction.source       = "APP"
transaction.tableName    = "TABLE_NAME"
transaction.fieldName    = "FIELD_NAME"
transaction.fieldValue   = "FIELD_VALUE"
transaction.objectId     = "OBJECT_ID"

def changeNumber = Transaction.createCriteria().get {
    eq("objid", currentTransaction.objid)
    eq("tableName", currentTransaction.tableName)
    projections {
        max("changeNumber")
    }
}

currentTransaction.changeNumber = (changeNumber ?: 0) + 1

if(!transaction.save()) {
    transaction.errors.each {
        println it
    }

    response = [code: 'error transaction', status: 500]
}

return response
```

And finally, here's my unit test code:

```
void testTransaction() {
    when:
    def response = testService.loadTransaction() // Creates transaction row

    then:
    assert response == [code: 'OK']
    assert Transaction.count() == 1
}
```

The domain structure was defined by another party, and I can't change it in any way, so the composite key is a must.  Unfortunately many classes in this app use composite keys, so if I can't unit test them, a lot of my code can't be covered by unit testing.  Any info to get me going in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use unit tests to test persistence.

Unit tests have a GORM implementation, but it isn't backed by a database, only a `ConcurrentHashMap`. It's pretty good, but it should only ever be used to avoid having to mock the persistence layer when unit testing other artifact types like controllers. If you want to test persistence, use a database.

Otherwise, you'll see funky issues like this, and similar issues like false negatives or worse - false positives where a test passes that shouldn't, leaving bugs in your "well-tested" code.